# how to copy only the files that changed in svn

Tags: svn, ftp, file-copying

I have a project in my svn. I want to copy it at server.

I can export current revision from svn to my local directory. Than write a config file and copy with use of ftp to the server. Is it possible to do it in an inteligent way? I. e. copy only files which changed?

What I want is to write something like Makefile for putting revisions on server, I'll be grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/) to synchronize your local copy with a server.

Answer (score 3):

You could prepare a patch with `svn diff` and apply it on your server.